# Identifying a mushroom (Switzerland)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know this type of mushroom? It grew during the last week in large numbers in one of my pots on the balcony, location Zurich, Switzerland. A smaller part of the soil is from the wood in the neighbourhood, so it might have originated from there.

I spent some time researching on the Internet, and think it might be related to the Armillaria family. An expert opinion would be very much appreciated.